# Firefox doesn't run through selenium grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-grid

After upgrading Firefox to version 35.0 I can't run functional tests on it. I am using Selenium Grid.

Linux 3.16.1-1-apparmor x86_64
Archlinux

selenium-server 2.44.0;
FF 35.0

```
bundle exec cucumber features/ -p firefox
Process timed out after waiting for 45000 ms. (java.lang.InterruptedException) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess(UnixProcess.java):148:in `waitFor'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine(CommandLine.java):129:in `waitFor'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary(FirefoxBinary.java):222:in `waitFor'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary(FirefoxBinary.java):242:in `clean'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java):91:in `start'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriver.java):246:in `startClient'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver(RemoteWebDriver.java):114:in `<init>'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriver.java):193:in `<init>'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriver.java):186:in `<init>'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriver.java):104:in `<init>'
[remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):-2:in `newInstance0'
[remote server] sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java):57:in `newInstance'
[remote server] sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java):45:in `newInstance'
[remote server] java.lang.reflect.Constructor(Constructor.java):526:in `newInstance'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider(DefaultDriverProvider.java):59:in `callConstructor'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider(DefaultDriverProvider.java):53:in `newInstance'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory(DefaultDriverFactory.java):54:in `newInstance'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator(DefaultSession.java):214:in `call'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator(DefaultSession.java):1:in `call'
[remote server] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask(FutureTask.java):262:in `run'
[remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1(DefaultSession.java):168:in `run'
[remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):1145:in `runWorker'
[remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):615:in `run'
[remote server] java.lang.Thread(Thread.java):744:in `run'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:640:in `raw_execute'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:101:in `create_session'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in `new'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:33:in `for'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.44.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.11/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bundler/gems/test_core-1e3a7755532c/lib/test_core/support/env.rb:25:in `new'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bundler/gems/test_core-1e3a7755532c/lib/test_core/support/env.rb:25:in `remote_browser'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bundler/gems/test_core-1e3a7755532c/lib/test_core/support/env.rb:20:in `browser'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bundler/gems/test_core-1e3a7755532c/lib/test_core/support/hooks.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bundler/gems/test_core-1e3a7755532c/lib/test_core.rb:3:in `require'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bundler/gems/test_core-1e3a7755532c/lib/test_core.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/work/tmp/billing/features/support/env.rb:1:in `require'
/home/user/work/tmp/billing/features/support/env.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:95:in `load_code_file'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/cucumber-1.3.18/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

If I just run FF:

```
# firefox -v

(process:6367): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Mozilla Firefox 35.0
```

Browsers run via vnc server.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium WebDriver 2.44.0 is not supporting FF35 yet.
(see https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG)

Try to downgrade your FF to get the full support.

Comment: Downgraded to 34 and then to 33. Still have the same error